# Repetition of Mathematical Expression

Tags: c++

I want to create a program that will continue to repeat until both operands contain a zero. For example, 0 + 0 should terminate the program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  double num1, num2;
  char symbol;

  cin>>num1>>symbol>>num2;

  while (num1 !=0 && num2 !=0) 
  {
    switch (symbol) 
     {
      case '+': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2 << endl;
      break;
      case '-': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2 << endl;
      break;
      case 'X': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2 << endl;
      break;
      case 'x': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2 << endl;
      break;
      case '*': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2 << endl;
      break;
      case '/': cout << num1 << " " << symbol << " " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2 << endl;
      break;
      default: cout << "Invalid symbol" << endl;
    }
    cin>>num1>>symbol>>num2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Having trouble with this input -
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information (including input) directly in the question as text.

Comment: Right now your while-loop continues until *at least one operand is zero*, but you want it to continue until *both operands are zero*.  Replacing the `&&` with `||` will get you the behavior you want.

Comment: Btw if you want you can use De Morgan's law to convert the expression into one that  more closesly resembles your English-language phrasing of the condition, i.e. "continue to repeat until both operands equal 0" can be written as `while( !( (num1==0)&&(num2==0) ) )`